# Trouble with converting a xml into a csv with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, csv, converters

So I have this unconventional xml that I want to convert into a csv, I've gotten to a point where I don't know where to look any further.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
-<Records count="88">

-<Record parentId="0" moduleId="618" levelGuid="bf1e60be-cae0-428d-88eb-60cce2ca7e80" levelId="416" contentId="889443">
<Field type="1" guid="55ef2cec-bcff-4bff-ad83-43f55205fad2" id="24035">Exception Requests >> Exception Requests</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="de997cd6-e53c-4ff1-81e9-17a9f98b3043" id="24036">Name</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="d4d1d2ad-c4af-454a-afad-851617a94874" id="24037">Additional Access</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="0f464953-42d1-4487-96b1-6b3d1ba85558" id="24038">Accès supplémentaire</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="91cf5fd2-70dc-4e37-bca9-046851e2c763" id="24039">cada8def-650f-443d-9ef3-53b74ecc16b2</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="5a5bdeb2-8f98-4f56-8c77-e1294b4e1cf1" id="24040">476</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="2a67dc86-c01d-4927-8a08-7557543248d2" id="24041">1</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="395a0e50-52cd-4d61-8653-94ad41f5d7da" id="24042">b809048d0be00ec524a7c7c95c1a1f8a</Field>
</Record>

-<Record parentId="0" moduleId="618" levelGuid="bf1e60be-cae0-428d-88eb-60cce2ca7e80" levelId="416" contentId="889317">
<Field type="1" guid="55ef2cec-bcff-4bff-ad83-43f55205fad2" id="24035">Exception Request Extensions >> Exception Request Extensions</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="de997cd6-e53c-4ff1-81e9-17a9f98b3043" id="24036">Name</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="d4d1d2ad-c4af-454a-afad-851617a94874" id="24037">Most Recent Approved Expiration Date Helper</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="0f464953-42d1-4487-96b1-6b3d1ba85558" id="24038">Aide sur la date max.</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="91cf5fd2-70dc-4e37-bca9-046851e2c763" id="24039">8b3fbad5-2806-4a64-8e2b-fe5dfaa4562d</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="5a5bdeb2-8f98-4f56-8c77-e1294b4e1cf1" id="24040">8098</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="2a67dc86-c01d-4927-8a08-7557543248d2" id="24041">1</Field>
<Field type="1" guid="395a0e50-52cd-4d61-8653-94ad41f5d7da" id="24042">594a6240a3a606cf9720189a5f15980c</Field>
</Record>
</Records>
```

What I want is to get the fields of every record to be columns, id can be used as the name and the text after is to be the value. (last picture)

For now this is what I have:

```html
#read from file
"reading..."
[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content "Exportation_Field.xml"
"exporting..."
#export xml as csv
if ($inputFile.Records.childnodes )
    {
    $inputFile.Records.record.childnodes | Select-Object "#text" | Export-Csv "exportCSV.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:";" -Encoding:UTF8 
    "complete"
    }
```

This returns all the `#text` of all the fields one after another in a single column.

This is what I want to get: [outputCSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1EX8.png)

I have a feeling that some sort of loop might help, but being new at PowerShell I don`t know how to use them in this context.

This is the expected result:

[expectedCSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHdXs.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sample XML is invalid, missing closing records?

Comment: its because there are 88 records, putting the whole thing might have been too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll need to do in order to get your desired result is to make objects with each ID as a property. There are many tools at our disposal, for this example I'll use `Select-XML`

```
select-xml -Path "Exportation_Field.xml" -XPath "//Record" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.node.field | ForEach-Object -Begin {$hash = [ordered]@{}} -Process {
            $hash.add($_.id,$_.'#text')
        } -End {[PSCustomObject]$hash}
}
```

With this example, you'll end up with 2 objects

```
24035 : Exception Requests >> Exception Requests
24036 : Name
24037 : Additional Access
24038 : Accès supplémentaire
24039 : cada8def-650f-443d-9ef3-53b74ecc16b2
24040 : 476
24041 : 1
24042 : b809048d0be00ec524a7c7c95c1a1f8a

24035 : Exception Request Extensions >> Exception Request Extensions
24036 : Name
24037 : Most Recent Approved Expiration Date Helper
24038 : Aide sur la date max.
24039 : 8b3fbad5-2806-4a64-8e2b-fe5dfaa4562d
24040 : 8098
24041 : 1
24042 : 594a6240a3a606cf9720189a5f15980c
```

Simply add `Export-Csv` to the end. I chose to use the `-Begin` and `-End` parameters of the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet, this could also be written as such.

```
select-xml -Path "Exportation_Field.xml" -XPath "//Record" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $hash = [ordered]@{}
        $_.node.field | ForEach-Object {
            $hash.add($_.id,$_.'#text')
        }
        [PSCustomObject]$hash
} | Export-Csv -Path OutFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thank you, its wroked,
I just had to add -Delimiter:";" -Encoding:UTF8 after -noTypeInformation.

Comment: Great! Please consider accepting it as the solution by clicking the checkmark. That way other users know it's a valid answer.